# "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[id]'" When trying to get all id elements in selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver in python. This function is supposed to include these id's in a list if they match a certain pattern

```
class elemtnals:


def __init__(self, driver):
 self.driver= driver
 self.sl = SeleniumExtended(self.driver)

def identifier(self):


 elements = self.sl.wait_until_visibility_of_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[id]')

 pattern = r'[A-D][0-2][a-z]'

 matching_elements = [element for element in elements if re.fullmatch(pattern, element.get_attribute("id"))]


 print(matching_elements)




 return matching_elements
```

The wait_until_visibility_of_elements is this function:

```
   def wait_until_visibility_of_elements(self, locator, timeout=None):

    timeout= timeout if timeout else self.default_timeout
    try:
     WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located(locator))
    except TimeoutException:
        raise Exception(f"Element/s: {locator} not displayed with after timeout of {timeout} ")
```

When this function is requested I get the following error:

"ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[id]'"

and yes I imported 're'

traceback

```
poll_frequency = 0.5, ignored_exceptions = None

   def __init__(
       self,
       driver,
       timeout: float,
       poll_frequency: float = POLL_FREQUENCY,
       ignored_exceptions: typing.Optional[WaitExcTypes] = None,
   ):
       """Constructor, takes a WebDriver instance and timeout in seconds.

       :Args:
        - driver - Instance of WebDriver (Ie, Firefox, Chrome or Remote) or a WebElement
        - timeout - Number of seconds before timing out
        - poll_frequency - sleep interval between calls
          By default, it is 0.5 second.
        - ignored_exceptions - iterable structure of exception classes ignored during calls.
          By default, it contains NoSuchElementException only.

       Example::

        from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait \n
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda x: x.find_element(By.ID, "someId")) \n
        is_disappeared = WebDriverWait(driver, 30, 1, (ElementNotVisibleException)).\\ \n
                    until_not(lambda x: x.find_element(By.ID, "someId").is_displayed())
       """
       self._driver = driver
>       self._timeout = float(timeout)
E       ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[id]'
```

Comment: I don't see any code here that calls `float()`.  So the actual error must be elsewhere.  It's very hard to help when you don't show the specific code that has the error...

Comment: Please post the entire traceback message so we see where this happened.

Comment: apologies, I have now implemented the traceback

Comment: That's not what's meant by a traceback, it means the error message and all associated information that's produced when the error occurs - see https://realpython.com/python-traceback/